# java wsimport string

Tags: java, class, wsimport

I'm having an issue while trying to generate some Java classes.

```
C:\Users\kon\Desktop>wsimport -keep -verbose -extension -d generated http://XXXXXXWebServicesPort?wsdl
parsing WSDL...

[INFO] Trying to read authorization file : "C:\Users\kon\.metro\auth"...

[ERROR] Schema descriptor {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string in message part "return" is not defined and could not be bound to Java. Perhaps the schema descriptor {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSche
ma}string is not defined in the schema imported/included in the WSDL. You can either add such imports/includes or run wsimport and provide the schema location using -b switch.
  line 81 of http://XXXXXXWebServicesPort?wsdl
```

Here the content at line 81:

```
<message name="getJDBCConnectionURLOutput">
    <part name="return" element="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

I haven't used wsimport before and could not find any similar issue on the web. Is this a spelling issue?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any control character between the ':' and the 's' of xsd:string @81 ?

Comment: I checked this with WireShark, but it seams to be correct: [link](http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/5594/stringh.png)

Comment: Have you had a read of my answer below?

Comment: maybe xs:string ? That's depend on the prefix you choose for the namespace

Comment: That's the prefix that is defined in the header xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the WSDL is wrong.

It thinks you're pointing to an element called xsd:string which is defined earlier in the WSDL.

So xsd:string is incorrect, it should be some type you've defined earlier.

Compare it to some examples here: http://www.w3.org/2001/03/14-annotated-WSDL-examples

HTH

Edit: You can't define it as being string type like that directly.
Maybe you meant this:

```
<part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
```

Edit: Maybe this info in the WSDL spec will help:
http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_soap:body

Comment: hey @davidfrancis, thank you for your help. The xsd:string is defined in xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema". I  colleague told me that some parser having an issue with string. The latest version of axis is supposed to work right. I could find any bug-reports for this statement.

Comment: Maybe that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Also see my edit re: WSDL spec - how this works depends on the style and encoding you're using